# Calling a Class function from within a class in Javascript, Jquery

Tags: javascript

This is what I am trying to do and it isn't working, Error it is showing is : this.run is not a function. on the line ( this.xId = window.setInterval( 'this.run()', 2500 ); )

```
function(){

   this.run = function(){

      DO SOMETHING;

   }

   this.xId = window.setInterval( 'this.run()', 2500 );

}
```

What could be the reason ?

Comment: Because the string `"this.run()"` is evaluated in global scope and there, `this` refers to `window`. I assume you don't have a function `run` in global scope.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass anonymously function for that:

```
this.xId = window.setInterval( function() { this.run() }, 2500 );
```

Or better is to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind?action=edit) this function with `this` context:

```
this.xId = window.setInterval( this.run.bind(this) , 2500 );
```

Note that `bind` are implemented in  ECMA-262, 5th edition, so for crossbrowser compatibility you need to add this:

```
if (!Function.prototype.bind) {  
  Function.prototype.bind = function (oThis) {  
    if (typeof this !== "function") {  
      // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5 internal IsCallable function  
      throw new TypeError("Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable");  
    }  

    var aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1),   
        fToBind = this,   
        fNOP = function () {},  
        fBound = function () {  
          return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP  
                                 ? this  
                                 : oThis || window,  
                               aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));  
        };  

    fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;  
    fBound.prototype = new fNOP();  

    return fBound;  
  };  
}
```

Comment: Can the function be invoked like this `window.setInterval(this.run,2500 )` ?; If not pls explain the difference ?

Comment: The bind version worked, thanks. But I am confused about the "ECMA-262, 5th edition", where am I supposed to add it ?

Comment: Add this to some `js` file that is included on top of all pages.

Answer (score 0):

- First of all, [use a function reference rather than a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout#Passing_string_literals) for the timeout callback. the `this` when using a string is the global object, and not what might have provided it.
- Secondly, cache the value of `this`. The `this` in the callback may not be the same as the one outside it (which is the one attached with `run`).

  ```
  function(){
      var that = this; //cache "this"

      this.run = function(){
          //DO SOMETHING;
      }

      this.xId = window.setInterval(function(){
          that.run()
      },2500);
  }
  ```

Comment: As an alternative to "caching the value of `this`" you could use the bind function as described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#With_setTimeout